# Erro em API WEB com flask

Tags: python, json, asp.net-web-api, flask, python-requests

Iniciei meu estudo de API WEB tentando criar uma API Pokedex, Quando tentei criar a função de buscar pokemon pelo numero surgiu o seguinte erro:

"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

appPokedex:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/podekex', methods=['GET'])
def pokedex():
    return jsonify({
        'pokedex':[
            {
                'numero': 1,
                'nome':'bulbasuar',
                'type':('grass','poison')
            },
            {
                'numero': 2,
                'nome':'ivysuar',
                'type':('grass','poison')
            },
            {
                'numero': 3,
                'nome':'venusuar',
                'type':('grass','poison')
            },
            {
                'numero': 4,
                'nome':'charmander',
                'type':('fire')
           },
           {
                'numero': 5,
                'nome':'charmeleon',
                'type':('fire')
           },
           {
                'numero': 6,
                'nome':'charizard',
                'type':('fire','flying')
           },
           {
                'numero': 7,
                'nome':'squirtle',
                'type':('water')
           },
           {
                'numero': 8,
                'nome':'wartortle',
                'type':('water')
           },
           {
                'numero': 9,
                'nome':'blastoise',
                'type':('water')
            },
          ]
       })

@app.route('/<int:numero>', methods=['GET'])
def getNome(numero):
    p = pokedex()
    for pokemon in p['pokedex']:
        if pokemon['numero'] == numero:
            return jsonify(pokemon)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=80)
```

clientPokedex:

```
import requests as req

url_pokedex = "http://127.0.0.1/podekex"

pokedex = req.api.get(url_pokedex).json()
print(pokedex)

url_busca_num = "http://127.0.0.1/1"
pokemon = req.api.get(url_busca_num).json()
print(pokemon)
```

ERRO:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\EmersonCarbonaro\OneDrive\Documentos\Estudo\Faculdade\terceiro_semestre\aplicações_distribuidas\aula_07\estudo\pokedex\clientPokedex.py", line 9, in <module>
    pokemon = req.api.get(url_busca_num).json()
  File "C:\Users\Emerson Carbonaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Emerson Carbonaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Emerson Carbonaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Emerson Carbonaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembre-se de que json nada mais é do que uma string.

Quando você chama `p = pokedex()`, está botando em `p` o que a sua função `pokedex` retorna, que é uma `Response` do flask com `data` sendo uma string em formato json, e não um dicionário Python.

Você pode iterar sobre um dicionário se transformar o json em um dicionário:

```
import json
...
p = json.loads(pokedex().data)
```

Mas talvez uma solução melhor seja ter a pokedex como um dicionário em seu escopo global, e chamar `jsonify` nesse dicionário dentro da função `pokedex`.